# Instruction Definitions "Documentation" confusion

Tags: assembly, 68000

Im reading the documentation or whatever the term is for the instruction definitions and I'm confused as to what a lot of it means.

"Operation: source destination -> destination" what does that mean. What does that tell me?

"Assembler Syntax: ADD , Dn       ADD Dn, " Does that mean I can put the destination in either place? That ADD D0,#33 would do the same thing as ADD #33,D0?

Comment: You've left out a lot of information to help make this a good question. One thing is that you're missing a `+` in your second paragraph. You also haven't checked that the question appears as you want. The `<ea>` are being removed in the third paragraph.

Comment: No, you can't do `ADD D0,#33.` If you think of Motorola 68000 as the thing to the left of the comma being the source and the thing on the right being the destination, it's a lot easier. Now it gets a bit complicated with the more complex addressing modes, for example `MOVE.W (A0,D0),D1` means "temporarily add `D0` to `A0` and load the 16-bit value at that address into the low half of `D1`, and `A0` is not changed afterwards."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This information is taken from the "M68000 Family Programmer's Reference Manual". I assume that you're using this manual, or other documentation that contains a subset of it. In that document, the reference for `ADD` is on pages 4-4 through 4-6, and the Instruction Summary starts on page 3-1.

---

For the first question about:

```
Operation:
 Source + Destination → Destination
```

That's telling you the operation that's being done. The value in the source and is added to the current value in the destination, and that sum is stored in the destination.

---

For the second question, this concerns the two types of instructions that exist for `ADD`:

```
Assembler Syntax:
 ADD <ea>, Dn
 ADD Dn, <ea>
```

What you say is incorrect, this is not telling you that you can write it either way, and it have the same effect. This is specifying what types of parameters can be given to the instruction.

Specifically, while one argument can be any (sensible) effective address, at least one of the two arguments (either the source or the destination) must be a data register.

---

One apparent point of confusion you have is on identifying the source vs. the destination. It's important to read the Instruction Summary (Section 3.1 of the PRM) to understand how assembly instructions are written.

Importantly, that section has a table describing the various symbols used in instructions. It also states the following:

> In the operand syntax statements of the instruction definitions, the operand on the right is the destination operand.

So, writing `ADD #33, D0` means that the number `33` is added to the value in register `D0`, and then the result of that addition is stored back in register `D0`.

---

With the two options for writing the instruction, either the source or the destination must be a data register, with the other being an effective address. That effective address could be an address register, the value in memory pointed-to by an address register (possibly pre-decremented, post-incremented, offset, etc.), an integer value, etc.

For example, you might add the value in `D3` to the value stored at the address held in `A2` (represented as `(A2)`). In that case, the processor will read the memory at the address in `A2`, add the value in `D3` to that, and then store it back at that same address. This would be written as `ADD D3, (A2)`.

However, not all effective address types are sensible in all places. For example, the `ADD D0, #33` you give isn't a valid assembly instruction, since an immediate value isn't a valid destination. You can't store a value in the number 33.

You can see that the effective address destination operation tables for `ADD` have several entries that are shown as invalid, compared to the equivalent source effective address tables.

Comment: If I wanted to be pedantic, I would add that `ADD #33, D0` is actually not a valid instruction, but any sane assembler should translate it to `ADDI.w #33, D0` ("ADD Immediate").

Comment: @chtz I was thinking the same while writing the answer, since the manual does say that `ADDI` or `ADDQ` should be used. It does however specify the encoding in the source tables for an immediate, which left me a little confused, so I left that part out.

Comment: Yes, it is probably not relevant for OP's issue ...

Comment: Ok, looking into the manual again, it seems indeed possible to use `add.w #33,d0` as well as `addi.w #33,d0` -- I'm confused now as well ...

Comment: Without actually executing the instruction on hardware to see what happens, I'd guess that it's a valid instruction, but the documentation doesn't distinguish between "is an invalid instruction" and "should be assembled to a different instruction, though it is still valid". One disassembler I tried sees it as valid, but those are based on documentation so that doesn't mean anything.

Comment: `addi.w #33,d0`  and `add.w #33,d0` are in fact two different instructions that do exactly the same thing (with the same number of bytes of code and the same amount of cycles) - a bit of a quirk in the 68000's instruction set.

Comment: @chtz In terms of machine code they are encoded differently, but the assembler can manage that for you. They're encoded differently so that the CPU knows to add a constant `#33` rather than the 16-bit value at memory address 33.

Comment: @puppydrum64 `add.w 33,d0` is different than `add.w #33,d0` of course. The point of this discussion was that `add.w #33,d0` and `addi.w #33,d0` are different instructions which do exactly the same. The "normal" `add` instruction has to have at least on `d` register as source or destination, while the `addi` instruction can have any (writable) effective address as destination. The designers could have prohibited immediate values as source for the normal `add` instruction (and use that bitpattern for something else) without losing any functionality.